# Looking for a tool to record and resend http requests from my browser

Tags: httprequest, send

In order to do some testing I'm looking for a tool to make http requests. Most of my request have several parameters and options set up on the request. I had been spending a lot of time copying each parameter and each option. I don't want a software or some plugin to make http requests. I'm looking for a tool that make me able to listen and record the http request that my browser does, and later let me modify them, and send them again. Is there some tool like that?

Comment: Working on an add-on to Postman which helps you record requests. Demo here: www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH_W2-WbcyI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome I use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). It keeps a running log of all requests that have been made so it's easy to go back to previous ones. You can also save requests into collections.

In Firefox, try [HTTP Resource Test](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-resource-test/).

EDIT: After more careful reading I see you want to actually record and re-send requests. I believe [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) may allow you to do that.

Also, you could export the network log (e.g. from the Chrome developer tools page) to a [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) file and write a script to replay the requests. Or import the HAR file back into existing tools. See this thread for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/360992/what-format-does-google-chrome-developer-tools-save-data-as